# How to make entire array null if every element of array of struct is null in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with array of struct field. I need to make entire array null if every struct value is null within array.

```
id        arstr
----------------
123      [{arid:null,cd:null,value:null}]
111      [{arid:1,cd:'a',value:200},{arid:2,cd:'b',value:300}]

output should be:
id        arstr
----------------
123      NULL
111      [{arid:1,cd:'a',value:200},{arid:2,cd:'b',value:300}]

>>>df.printSchema()
root
 |--id: string (nullable = true)
 |--arstr: array (nullable = true)
 |   |--element: struct (containsNulll = true)
 |   |   |--arid: string (nullable =true)
 |   |   |--cd: string (nullable =true)
 |   |   |--value: integer (nullable =true)
```

But I have n number of array of struct fields like arstr. So I want to iterate through all columns using for loop.

```
df2=df.select('id',when(col(var1).var2[0].isNull(), None).otherwise(var1)
```

how to pass variables in place of var1 and var2 without column object callable error.

Comment: In your example it's not the struct element which is null but its fields, so you'll need to check each field

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that will have 1 if all fields within the struct is null else 0. Add the elements in this array to get the number of structs that are null. Here's an example with a dummy data. *Replace `_1`, `_2`, etc. with your fields inside the struct.*

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('ele_is_null_arr', func.expr('transform(struct_arr, x -> if(x._1 is null and x._2 is null and x._3 is null and x._4 is null, 1, 0))')). \
    withColumn('num_null_eles', func.expr('aggregate(ele_is_null_arr, 0, (x, y) -> x + y)')). \
    withColumn('new_struct_arr',
               func.when(func.col('num_null_eles') < func.size('struct_arr'), func.col('struct_arr')).
               otherwise(func.lit(None))
               ). \
    select('struct_arr', 'new_struct_arr'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
# |struct_arr                                             |new_struct_arr                                         |
# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{null, null, null, null}]                             |null                                                   |
# |[{xyz, 30-09-2020, 13, SAF}, {xyz, 31-12-2020, 12, AF}]|[{xyz, 30-09-2020, 13, SAF}, {xyz, 31-12-2020, 12, AF}]|
# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

If there is at least 1 non-null field in the struct, it will not update to *null*.

```
# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
# |struct_arr                                             |new_struct_arr                                         |
# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{null, null, null, null}, {null, null, 20, null}]     |[{null, null, null, null}, {null, null, 20, null}]     |
# |[{xyz, 30-09-2020, 13, SAF}, {xyz, 31-12-2020, 12, AF}]|[{xyz, 30-09-2020, 13, SAF}, {xyz, 31-12-2020, 12, AF}]|
# +-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```